# Не работает dotnet restore на Mac OS Ventura из приватного источника пакетов

Tags: macos, ssl, nuget

При попытке восстановить пакеты из командной строки или в Visual Studio For Mac выдается ошибка о невозможности подключения к приватному источнику пакетов из-за неверного сертификата.

Я добавил наш внутренний доменный центр сертификации и в системную связку ключей, и в /etc/ssl/cert.pem

В результате и Safari и curl без проблем подключаются к нашему источнику пакетов. Но dotnet restore по прежнему ругается на сертификат сервера.

Куда еще нужно прописать наш сертификат, чтобы заработал и dotnet restore?

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос снят.

Оказывается достаточно все же просто добавить сертификат в связку ключей.

Причиной проблемы оказалось то, что для нашего Azure DevOps Server был сгенерирован сертификат с ключом длины 1024 бита. После того, как я заменил на сертификат с длинной ключа 2048 бит - все заработало.